# Include table name in SQL query

Tags: sql, mysql

What I need to do is get a table name in result from a union query with 4 selects from different tables. I need to get the id and the table name for further processing.

For example i have table1, table2, table3 table4 and have a query:

```
SELECT id from table1,blablabla
UNION
SELECT id from table2,blablabla
UNION
SELECT id from table3,blablabla
UNION
SELECT id from table4,blablabla
```

And I need the result like:

```
1, blablabla, table1
4, blablabla, table4
7, blablabla, table2
```

Comment: Can you use the code tags, and show us exactly what you are after?

Comment: All the answers below (right now) suggest to hardcode it as a string.  Other things I've looked up talk about passing it as a variable to dynamic SQL.  What about automatically generating it?  Is there something like @@SERVERNAME?  `SELECT tablealias.@@TABLENAME FROM Table1 tablealias`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
SELECT
    ID,
    'table1' as TableName
FROM
    table1

UNION

...

SELECT
    ID,
    'table4' as TableName
FROM
    table4
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  myid, My otherfield, 'table1' as tablename From table1
UNION
SELECT  myid, My otherfield, 'mytabl2' From table2
```

Consider a couple of other points, if these are tables that are mutually exclusive use UNION ALL Instead, it will be much much faster. Also, this type of question often comes up when the database design is incorrect, if the same fields are in these tables, why are they not all in one table? Redesign if possible, at least consider if you would be better served doing this. Not knowing what that tables are, I can;t evelauate if they should be in one table, but usually this is a code smell.

Comment: Thanks for the information. At beginning it was one table, but new data come in other categories and the tables are now for different categories and hold similar data, but for security reason should be kept separate. Only this one query accesses more then one table and it's only for listing.

Answer (score 2):

Add the table name in your request

```
SELECT
  id,
  blablabla,
  'table1' as tableName
FROM
  table1
UNION
SELECT
  id,
  blablabla,
  'table2' as tableName
FROM
  table2
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Exacly what I needed but devnull was first so I accept his answer.